# Filtering a Collection using Linq based on Combo boxes Selections

Tags: wpf, linq, mvvm

i use the following code to filter a collection based on the user options which are captured via combo boxes and sent to view model or controller to implement a cascade filtering:

```
 IEnumerable<SubsystemDTO> _ssDTOs = _subsystemService
         .GetAllSubsystemsList()
          .Where(s => s.MS != null 
               && s.MS.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS) 
               && _subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS != "All")
          .Where(s => s.Flag != null 
               && s.Flag.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedFlag) 
               && _subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedFlag != "All")
          .Where(s => s.Scope != null 
               && s.Scope.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedScope)
               && _subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedScope != "All");
```

I have 3 combo boxes which collect the user options and they are applied to the collection in cascading manner as shown. The the data are fetched from a database which contain values equal to those passed by the combo boxes my questions are:

1.If the user choose not to filter by Flag for example, so he selects option All in that combo box how to apply that to the above linq query

2.Generally if the user wants to filter by a value in the combo box that doesn't has peer in the database how to do that (like All option in 1 or the invert of an option)

Note: i tried to add the statement [_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS != "All"] to exclude implementing the filter if all selection is selected by the user but  when selecting All option in one combo box, the result is an empty query result.

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question means - if a user searches for a value not in the database then which results would be returned?

Comment: @stuartd Sorry for not being clear enough i mean for example if you have marital Status field which contains the options: Single, Married, Divorced you can filter by one of these options which exist in the database or you may not want to filter by this field at all so you select All option which exist in the combo box but it is not a selection in the database or you may be want to filter by (Not Divorced) persons which also may be an option in the combo box but not a selection in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If the user choose not to filter by Flag for example, so he selects option All in that combo box how to apply that to the above linq query.*

You want to return the values where either the value matches what the user selected OR the user has selected 'All' values: this first example follows the pattern of your query above, and only returns values where the `SubsystemDTO` values (MS, Flag, Scope) are not null.

```
  .Where(s => s.MS != null 
     && (_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS == "All" 
     || s.MS.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS)))

  // etc
```

If you wanted to return all values regardless of whether the `SubsystemDTO` properties are populated, you would move the ALL check to the top:

```
  .Where(s => _subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS == "All"
     || (s.MS != null && s.MS.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS)))

  // etc
```

Edit:

To mix "Not' into this query you have to compare the result of the Equals comparison with whether or not the value 'Is' or "Is Not' the one specified by the user

If you had a view model property called `IsMatch` which was `true` when the user wanted to match the selected value, and `false` when the values which do not match the selected value:

```
 .Where(s => _subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS == "All"
    || (s.MS != null && s.MS.Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.SelectedMS)
                            .Equals(_subsystemRptPanelViewModel.IsMatch))

// etc
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine. just one concern which i added in the comments of the question: as per that comment if i want to select all excluding Divorced how to wire such option into the linq query.

Comment: Thanks again, i applied what you suggested in the Edit part of your answer and it is working very nicely.